# MIB validation - current group `sysInfoGroup' is not referenced in this module

Tags: validation, snmp, mib

I've sent my MIB to 3 validators :
https://www.muonics.com/Tools/smicheck.php : 0 error, 0 warning
https://www.agentpp.com/services/mibcheck.html : 0 error, 0 warning

but : 
https://www.simpleweb.org/ietf/mibs/validate/ : 3 warnings (severity 5)

does this last one true or mistaken ?

It's the same type of warning : *"warning: current group `sysInfoGroup' is not referenced in this module"*.

To reduce the code size, I've simplified it :

```
envMonitorMIB   OBJECT IDENTIFIER  ::= { nolmeMIB 1 }

info OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { envMonitorMIB 1 }

--  
--  SYSTEM SECTION
--
sysInfo  OBJECT IDENTIFIER  ::= { info 1 }

sysInfoGroup OBJECT-GROUP
    OBJECTS
    {
        systemCpuUsage,
        systemTotalMem,
        systemFreeMem,
        systemUptime,
        systemTemperature,
        cpuTemperature      
    }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "System informations."
 ::= { sysInfo 1 }


systemCpuUsage OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    UNITS       "%"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "cpu usage."
        ::= { sysInfo 2 }

systemTotalMem OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    UNITS       "Ko"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Total memory in Ko."
        ::= { sysInfo 3 }

systemFreeMem OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    UNITS       "Ko"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Free memory in Ko."
        ::= { sysInfo 4 }

systemUptime OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      TimeTicks
    UNITS       "Ko"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "System uptime in UNIT."
        ::= { sysInfo 5 }

systemTemperature OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    UNITS       "C"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "System temperature in degree C."
        ::= { sysInfo 6 }

cpuTemperature OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    UNITS       "C"
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "CPU temperature in degree C."
        ::= { sysInfo 7 }
```

Thanks for help.

Vincent

Comment: A vendor can have its own logic to validate, because the standard does not define what kind of warnings are mandatory. The differences among vendors are also negligible, as even if you do nothing about such warnings, the MIB document is still valid.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for this info but let's say I did want to fix this, what would be required? I have a notification-group with a notification-type in its NOTIFICATIONS but i still get this error. Not sure what else i would have to provide